# Create FTP User Accounts with Rails

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ftp-server

Ok I'm not sure how to approach or explain this but I'll give it a try.

I'm developing a rails app on my mac using Devise for auth.

I would like to do the following:

When a user joins the site, the app creates an ftp user account with the same login credentials (email/password) they used to sign up. That way they can upload files via ftp using the root url of the site and their login credentials.

When the user updates their login credentials, their ftp user account needs to be updated with the same credentials.

Does paperclipftp or carrierwaveftp handle this? What would be the best way to accomplish this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting up individual FTP accounts for each one of your site's users, [this post](http://offtheline.net/2009/1/6/ftp-authentication-via-rails) walks through writing a controller action that handles the FTP authentication response instead, using your Rails users' credentials. It uses [pure-ftpd](http://www.pureftpd.org/project/pure-ftpd) and a custom authentication module to send an HTTP request with the credentials to your Rails app, which will then verify them by whatever means you'd like, and return the appropriate FTP response to the client.

I haven't tried it out, but I'm working on the same issue and this approach makes sense to me.